# Are namespaces in PHP "inherited"?

Tags: php, drupal-7, namespaces

**EDIT:**

Yes the problem was using \ at the beginning of the `use` statement. As M1ke pointed out, `use` goes from the root element.

**Original post**

I think is a PHP question but it may be Drupal.

I'm working on a headless Drupal project where is using a class (which I call Entity Model) that uses a Drupal class called EntityFieldQuery.

Before a create or use this class I bootstrap Drupal using:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'/includes/bootstrap.inc';

drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

The entity model class is in the Models names space like so:

```
namespace Models;

use \EntityFieldQuery;

class EntityModel
{

    .....

     $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
     $query->doSomething();

    ......
}
```

The EntityFieldQuery is found perfectly as I use the "\" because this class is out of the Models namespace.

The problem is when this class is created is uses other classes that don't use any namespace, and I have the following error:

```
class Models\InsertQuery not found in ....
```

Here is the class used by EntityFieldQuery that uses InsertQuery

```
class InsertQuery_mysql extends InsertQuery ...
```

I don't understand why InsertQuery_mysql is found but InsertQuery

I ended up adding a "\" in InsertQuery to fix the problem like so:

```
class InsertQuery_mysql extends \InsertQuery ...
```

Actually this class in a php file called query.inc that contains two defitinion classes (in the same file, I don't know this is a a problem too)

```
class InsertQuery_mysql extends InsertQuery 
....
class TruncateQuery_mysql extends TruncateQuery
```

I thought that if I use "new \ClassName()" the "default namespace" inside this class would be "\" too and not the first called class's namespace.

I don't like to modify 3rd party libraries, is any way to avoid this? I guess is a architecture problem rather than a lack of definition if someone has a better idea, I appreciate.

Thanks!

**EDIT2: Adding more info...**

In order of execution.

index.php:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
...
```

app/SiteController.php:

```
use Models\Campaign;
class SiteController {
   ...
   $campaing = new Campaign();
   ...
```

app/Models/Campaing.php:

```
namespace Models;
class Campaign extends EntityModel {
...
```

app/Models/EntityModel.php:

```
namespace Models;

use \EntityFieldQuery; //<-- this should go without \ as I say in EDIT section
class EntityModel {
...
public function getAll() {
   $query = new EntityFieldQuery(); //<--throwed Models\InsertQuery not found. It must have \ at the beginning of the class name.
```

Comment: May you post the whole of the offending code? It's hard to see there which files have which namespaces/use declarations.

Comment: Additionally, you don't need a `\ ` before the namespace in a `use` declaration. `use` goes from the root element.

Comment: I thought I did this before (?), and when I changed by removing the \ and adding it to the new class statement It worked without having to change drupal libraries code. So thanks!

Comment: I've added to my answer. It would seem that your `app/Models/EntityModel.php` file also needs `namespace Models`, or does it have that?

Comment: It has models already.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to solve your original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the base question (and pending further code) PHP namespaces are set by whichever namespace is declared in the file.

```
// Bar.php

namespace Foo;

class Bar {}

// some other file

use Foo\Bar;

$test = new Bar(); //works

// different file

namespace Foo;

$test = new Bar(); // works

// another file

require 'Bar.php';

// won't work because we are not in namespace "Foo"
$test = new Bar();
```

In your specific case it the `use \EntityLoader` should be `use EntityLoader` because you're exiting the namespace you want to be inside.